# fscanf читает не все символы ASCII

Tags: c

подскажите что можно использовать вместо fscanf чтобы сосчитать ASCII символы например 0x1A, символ ""(стрелочка вправо) или любой другой? Я пробовал через fscanf сосчитать в переменную char но либо ничего не считывалось либо тупо читался предыдущий символ

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char symbol;
long cursorPos;
long fileSize;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    char ch;
    if ((fp=fopen(argv[1], "r"))==NULL) 
    {
        printf("Cannot open file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    fileSize = ftell(fp);
    while(cursorPos<fileSize) 
    {
        fseek(fp, cursorPos, SEEK_SET);
        fscanf(fp, "%c", &symbol);
        printf("%c", symbol);
        cursorPos++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

что получается при чтении файла[image: трабл]

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/ вот смотрю в таблицу символов и никак не могу найти тут стрелочку..Другие символы уже юникод будет..и состоят из нескольких байт а не 1 как в случае с ascii

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> сосчитать ASCII символы

Под словом **сосчитать** Вы имеете в виду **прочитать** ? Или Вам реально надо сосчитать **количество** разных символов пои их кодам?

> пробовал через fscanf сосчитать в переменную char

Так, разумеется, не получится. Дело в том, что ф-ции из семейства *scanf* работают в режими форматирования введённой строки. Они ждут появления символа перевода строки, после этого **выполняют** все действия, которые заданы клавишами стрелок, забоя и т.д. И только после этого выполняется запись принятых данных (с преобразованием!!!) в указанные переменные.

> что можно использовать вместо fscanf

Если Вы хотите читать **все** символы из входного потока, без всякого форматирования, то надо открывать файл в двоичном режиме и читать его функцией чтения данных без форматирования - *fread()*

Должно получиться нечто вроде:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    char unsigned char_buffer[1024];
    long fileSize;
    int j;

    if ((fp=fopen(argv[1], "rb"))==NULL) 
    {
        printf("Cannot open file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Определяем реальный размер файла
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    fileSize = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    // Ограничиваем чтение размером буфера
    if (fileSize > 1024) fileSize = 1024;

    // Читаем все символы файла за один раз
    fileSize = fread(char_buffer, 1, fileSize, fp);

    // Распечатываем результат
    for (j=0; j<fileSize; j++)
         printf("%d  %u %c  0x%2X\n", j, char_buffer[j], char_buffer[j], char_buffer[j]);

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

А если натравить эту программку на распечатку своего же исходного текста, то начало выдачи будет выглядеть так:

```
$ ./a.out sym.c 

0  35 #  0x23
1  105 i  0x69
2  110 n  0x6E
3  99 c  0x63
4  108 l  0x6C
5  117 u  0x75
6  100 d  0x64
7  101 e  0x65
8  32    0x20
9  60 <  0x3C
10  115 s  0x73
11  116 t  0x74
12  100 d  0x64
13  105 i  0x69
14  111 o  0x6F
15  46 .  0x2E
16  104 h  0x68
17  62 >  0x3E
18  10 
  0x A
```

На выдаче видно, что нормально обработаны символы перевода строки - 0x0A, которые при вводе *fscan()* пережёвываются внутри функции.